# Pycharm not showing print outputs, it does in Spyder though

Tags: pycharm

Recently moved to Pycharm from Spyder, ran the same program without any code changes and I only get one set of printed outputs (I need two) and exit code 0. In Spyder, both sets print their output correctly, in PyCharm, only one does.

I've tried emulating terminal in output console

This is the part that needs printing:

```
print(f"{item}: {ideal_output.get(item)} found, {round(percentage(ideal_output.get(item), len(words)), 2)}% of total words in document: {', '.join(string_list)}.")
```

This is the part that *does* print:

```
print('Sentiment Analysis:',summary, len(words))
print("Positive accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(pos_correct/pos_count*100, pos_count))
print("Negative accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(neg_correct/neg_count*100, neg_count))
```

I expect both print functions to actually print.

The full code is:

```
a_dict = { **omitted here, just a bunch of key/value pairs**

}

def percentage(part, whole):
  return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)

#list all the tuples into a big list for one iteration
one_big_list = list(item for items in a_dict.values() for item in items)

#build GUI for text file selection
import PySimpleGUI as sg
window_rows = [[sg.Text('Please select a .txt file for analysis')],
                 [sg.InputText(), sg.FileBrowse()],
                 [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]
window = sg.Window('SIMA', window_rows)
event, values = window.Read()
window.Close()
source_filename = values[0]

#Open selected text file and tokenize
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
f = open(source_filename, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
raw = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
import string
table = str.maketrans ('', '', string.punctuation)
words = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
words = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]

#dictionary iteration party
word_count_dict = {}
with open(source_filename, encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        for item in one_big_list:
            line_split = list(line.strip('\n').split(' ')) #break line into list of words by space and strip linebreak
            if item in line_split:
                #print(f"found {item} in {line}")  #comment out this line (and this comment) to see line context
                if item not in word_count_dict.keys():
                    word_count_dict[item] = line_split.count(item) #count the amount of times it's said if not exist
                else:
                    word_count_dict[item] = word_count_dict[item] + line_split.count(item) #add to existing if exists

#print(word_count_dict) #uncomment this line to see all tagged words and their counts
ideal_output = {}
for count in word_count_dict:
    for key, value in a_dict.items():
        if count in value:
            if key not in ideal_output:
                ideal_output[key] = word_count_dict.get(count)
            else:
                ideal_output[key] = ideal_output[key] + word_count_dict.get(count) #instead of how many instances

for item in ideal_output:
   string_list = []
   tuple_of_words = a_dict[item]
   for entry in tuple_of_words:
       get_times_said = word_count_dict.get(entry)
       if get_times_said:
           string_list.append(f"'{entry}': {get_times_said}")

   print(f"{item}: {ideal_output.get(item)} found, {round(percentage(ideal_output.get(item), len(words)), 2)}% of total words in document: {', '.join(string_list)}.")

   #sentiment analysis engine
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
summary = {"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0}
for x in words:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(x)
    if ss["compound"] == 0.0:
        summary["neutral"] +=1
    elif ss["compound"] > 0.0:
        summary["positive"] +=1
    else:
        summary["negative"] +=1

#printed outputs: sentiment analysis, frequency distribution, and collocations
print('Sentiment Analysis:',summary, len(words))

#sentiment analysis accuracy outputs
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

import time
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

pos_count = 0
pos_correct = 0

with open(source_filename, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['neg'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] > 0:
                pos_correct += 1
            pos_count += 1

neg_count = 0
neg_correct = 0

with open(source_filename, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['pos'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] <= 0:
                neg_correct += 1
            neg_count += 1

print("Positive accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(pos_correct/pos_count*100, pos_count))
print("Negative accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(neg_correct/neg_count*100, neg_count))
```

Comment: Please give some more details, like do you get an error? and the content of this code.

Comment: I don't get any errors. Just "Process Finished with Exit Code 0." The full code is has been edited into the original post.

Comment: It's a rather complex print statement. If you add a print('I got here') above it, does it get there?

Comment: Another thing you can do is add `print(ideal_output)` before this for loop `for item in ideal_output:`.  I suspect your for loop isn't being executed and thus neither is your print.  You know, standard debugging stuff as errors are often not what you think they are and are found when you dig deeper.  Dig deeper.